# CW paddle interface wiring problem

Tags: diy, cw

I have the [MFJ-564B](http://www.mfjenterprises.com/Product.php?productid=MFJ-564B) iambic paddle which I need to wire to the [MFJ-552](http://www.mfjenterprises.com/Product.php?productid=MFJ-552) CW interface. The paddle is stereo (dits/dahs) and the interface is mono (when connected to paddle, only gives DITS). How can I make a connector for it without rewiring my paddle? The paddle works perfectly with my other radios.

Answer (score 1):

As I read the MFJ-522 manual, it appears that you will need a keyer between your paddle and the 522.

Your paddle is essentially two switches, and a keyer is an electronic box (MFJ-401D, for example) that makes dots when you close one switch, and dashes when you close the other. The output of the keyer is a single switch contact that could be used to replace a manual key. If your other radios can use the paddle directly, they must have built-in keyers.

(This is a very strange use of mono/stereo terminology.)

Comment: I called MFJ and the guy was not motivated to help. Says i need to take a mono cable and rewire it to one side of the paddle, so i can get the DAH's instead of just dit's. He wouldn't explain in detail. I don't know of any HAM pages that handle questions the way this one does. the keyer IS the paddle. I also looked through the manual for something like a dip switch, but nothing. My radios handle it simply with a setting on or off.

Comment: Your paddle is essentially two switches, and a keyer is an electronic box (MFJ-401D, for example) that makes dots when you close one switch, and dashes when you close the other.  The output of the keyer is a single switch contact that could be used to replace a manual key.  If your other radios can use the paddle directly, they must have built-in keyers.

Comment: Mic Sherwood   -- have you considered the http://eham.net web site for questions such as these.  I think that eHam has a much wider audience of readers who could possibly contribute first hand knowledge.  You should consider using the Elmers Forum on eHam.